non-interactive single-threaded process limited by input-output (I/O)
I need to demonstrate that the number of threads of the previously identified process can change and that not every thread of the process needs to be created at the same time. How to do that?
I have this:
[root@251663 ttyid:1 nie kwi 21 19:27:09 s251663]# ps -o pid,nlwp,lwp,cmd,stime -L -p 2569

    PID NLWP     LWP CMD                         STIME

   2569    4    2569 /usr/bin/clipit             11:38

   2569    4    2631 /usr/bin/clipit             11:38

   2569    4    2632 /usr/bin/clipit             11:38

   2569    4    2640 /usr/bin/clipit             **11:38**

and need something like that:
[sysop@247648 ttyid:0 śro maj 03 16:13:02 /]$ ps -o pid,nlwp,lwp,cmd,stime -L -p 7257

 PID NLWP LWP CMD STIME

 7257 6 7257 /usr/bin/gigolo 16:07

 7257 6 7259 /usr/bin/gigolo 16:07

 7257 6 7260 /usr/bin/gigolo 16:07

 7257 6 7261 /usr/bin/gigolo 16:07

 7257 6 7263 /usr/bin/gigolo 16:07

 7257 6 **10462** /usr/bin/gigolo **16:13**

[sysop@247648 ttyid:0 śro maj 03 16:13:16 /]$

How to make a new thread?

Why do you need to demonstate that? It's common knowledge. Common programming languages like C and C++ create one main thread of execution at startup

Nothing too do with PostScript.

You start the threads at different times, so wait a while before you start the next thread.
As a simple demonstration:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *thread_function(void *arg) {
    int thread_num = *((int *)arg);
    printf("Dit is thread %d\n", thread_num);
    sleep(300);
    printf("Einde thread %d\n", thread_num);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threads[3];
    int thread_args[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        thread_args[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_function, &thread_args[i]);
        sleep(60);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}

